# Check file permissions for another user

Tags: linux, file-permissions, user

Apache is complaining about not being able to access a file. Is there an easy way to find out what is blocking the access?

I know that I can go through the process of knowing which groups the user belongs to, checking permissions by doing an `ls -ld` on every folder in the path to the file, and a final `ls -l` on the file itself, but that's pretty tedious. Then there's also selinux and file ACLs that could also be in play.

I also know that I can change apache's login shell from `/sbin/nologin` to `/bin/bash`, then `su - apache` and `cd` through the folders until I can't, but that is also tedious.

It's something that I do often and I suspect others do as well, so I assume there's something I'm missing that makes this easier.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.  I would like to think the following will be more helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash

uid=`id -u`

echo $uid

cmd='find . ! \( -user '${uid}

echo $cmd

for gid in `id -G`
do
    cmd=${cmd}' -o -gid '${gid}
done

cmd=$cmd' \)'

echo "..."
echo $cmd

for file in `find . ! \( -gid 1000 \)`
do
    a=$((`stat ${file} --print=%a`%10))

    if [ $a -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: That finds files owned by the user in question. I want to know whether the user in question has read access to a file. They could have read access even if the file isn't owned by them by being a member of a group with read access, or alternatively they could be denied access because they don't have access to the folder that the file is in.